# Need to see if I calculated Digital Logic Levels Correctly for Interface

Tags: interface, lvcmos

I am trying to see if I calculated the correct current values for the following interfaces.

The first interface shows no margin at Voh-Vih as they are identical, but the LS1046 was tested at IOH=.5mA which I am assuming the current needed by the VSC8540 is much less. The VSC8540 datasheet says that it only needs 48uA for input current (well below .5mA) which means that VOH for the LS1046 will be higher. But added into the circuit is a 33 ohm series terminator resistor. If this is added, how does this change the Input current needed by the VSC8540?

Is it just I=1.35/33+57K (or 155K)? Do I need to add in the Iin current as well? Also is there a way to tell how much higher the Voh will be under these conditions?

Thanks!

[image: First Interface[!][1]][1]]

Comment: VOH/IOH gives you the LS1046 output impedance, which you can model as another resistor. Just check with the worst-case input current.

Comment: Can you find an IBIS model for the LS1046?  That would be better at providing you the output resistance (which may not be linear wrt output voltage) as a function of Voh, than just the simple Voh/Ioh calculation.

Comment: As @SteveSh said, treating digital logic inputs and outputs as equivalent resistors is not likely to be accurate. You could use Voh and Ioh to calculate an effective resistance, but that resistance value is only correct when the output voltage is equal to Voh and the output current is equal to Ioh. You can't assume that you can linearly extrapolate to other voltages/currents.